# Строковый калькулятор. Ошибка присваивания значения

Tags: c#

У меня есть стак, в котором хранятся числа. (1, 2, 3, 4, 2 ...)
Я беру последние два числа (сначала 2 потому 4 по логике) и передаю методу, который выполняет операцию (деление, но это не важно могут быть также +, -, *)
Для проверки я вывожу (number2 + " " + operation + " " + number1) выражение в консоль.
И получается выводится 2 / 2, вместо 4 / 2 (вычисляется соответственно).
Я поменял 2 -> 1 и теперь выводит 1/1, вместо 4 / 2 (вычисляется соответственно).
Так же я думал что проблема в передаче и стал присваивать отдельно и передавать, но проблема осталась.

Код будет главный метод класса (EquationSolution) и метод вычисления (Сalculation).
Внизу отдельно запишу класс Stack (Написал сам по методичке)

```
public double EquationSolution(string str)
    {
        //Индикатор конца строки
        str += '!';

        //Удалим пробелы
        str = str.Replace(" ", "");

        //Проверим правильность введённой строки
        string mistake = CheckingTheEnteredString(str);
        if (mistake != "")
        {
            //Если есть ошибки, то выведем в консоль ошибку

            Console.WriteLine(mistake);
            return -1;
        }

        //Храним числа
        var numbers = new Models.Stack<double>();
        //Храним число пока полностью не считаем из строки
        string number = "";
        double number1, number2; 

        //Храним операции Операции
        var operetions = new Models.Stack<char>();
        char[] elements = { '(', ')', '*', '/', '+', '-' };
        //Каждый раз писать str[0], чтобы взять первый элемент строки стало лень поэтому я выделил отдельный чар
        char e;

        while (str.Length != 0)
        {
            e = str[0];

            //Если это оператор или скобка
            if (elements.Any(element => element == e))
            {
                //Считываение числа закончилось, можно и в стек добавить
                if (number.Length != 0 && number != "-")
                {
                    numbers.Add(Convert.ToDouble(number));
                    number = "";
                }

                //Плюсик
                if (e == '+')
                {
                    while (!operetions.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        if (!(operetions.Look() == '('))
                        {
                            numbers.Add(Сalculation(numbers.PickUp(), numbers.PickUp(), operetions.PickUp()));
                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                    operetions.Add(e);
                }
                //Открывающая скобка
                else if (e == '(')
                {
                    operetions.Add('(');
                }
                //Умножить разделить
                else if(e == '*' || e == '/')
                {
                    if(operetions.IsEmpty || operetions.Look() == '+' || operetions.Look() == '-' || operetions.Look() == '(')
                    {
                        operetions.Add(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (!operetions.IsEmpty && operetions.Look() == '(')
                        {
                            numbers.Add(Сalculation(numbers.PickUp(), numbers.PickUp(), operetions.PickUp()));
                        }
                        operetions.Add(e);
                    }
                }
                //Закрывающая скобка
                else if (e == ')')
                {
                    while(operetions.Look() != '(')
                    {
                        numbers.Add(Сalculation(numbers.PickUp(), numbers.PickUp(), operetions.PickUp()));
                    }
                    operetions.Delete();
                }
                //Минус
                else
                {
                    if (numbers.IsEmpty )
                    {
                        number += '-';
                    }
                    else if(operetions.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        operetions.Add(e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (!operetions.IsEmpty)
                        {
                            if (!(operetions.Look() == '('))
                            {
                                number1 = numbers.PickUp();
                                number2 = numbers.PickUp();
                                numbers.Add(Сalculation(number1, number2, operetions.PickUp()));
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }
                        operetions.Add(e);
                    }
                }

            }

            //Если это конец строки                
            else if (e == '!')
            {
                if (number.Length != 0)
                {
                    numbers.Add(Convert.ToDouble(number));
                    number = "";
                }
                while (!operetions.IsEmpty)
                    numbers.Add(Сalculation(numbers.PickUp(), numbers.PickUp(), operetions.PickUp()));
            }

            //Это либо число, либо запятая
            else
            {
                number += e;
            }

            //Удаляем первый элемент строки
            str = str.Remove(0, 1);
        }
        return numbers.PickUp();
    }
    static double Сalculation(double number1, double number2, char operation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number2 + " " + operation + " " + number1);
        switch (operation)
        {
            case '+':
                return (double)(number1 + number2);
            case '-':
                return (double)(number2 - number1);
            case '*':
                return (double)(number1 * number2);
            case '/':
                return (double)(number2 / number1);
            
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

class Stack

```
{
    private List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public bool IsEmpty => items.Count == 0;


    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public T PickUp()
    {
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            var item = items.LastOrDefault();
            items.Remove(item);
            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            
            throw new NullReferenceException("Стек пуст");
        }

    }

    public T Look()
    {
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            return items.LastOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Стек пуст");
        }

    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        if (!IsEmpty)
        {
            var item = items.LastOrDefault();
            items.Remove(item);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Стек пуст");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка будет если в списке есть два и более одинаковых значения.

Ошибка здесь:

```
public T PickUp()
{
    if (!IsEmpty)
    {
        var item = items.LastOrDefault();
        items.Remove(item); // <- здесь
        return item;
    }
//...
```

Метод возвращает **последний** элемент из списка items, но удаляет не его, а **первое вхождение** этого значения (см. мануал к `Remove()`). Т.е. например после первого применения `PickUp()`  на список (1, 2, 3, 4, 2) останется не (1, 2, 3, 4), как вы думаете, а (1, 3, 4, 2). Удалится не последняя двойка, а первая.

Можно попробовать так:

```
items.RemoveAt(LastIndexOf(item));
```

*за работоспособность не ручаюсь, в с# не разбираюсь.*